# React Native - expo go not able to connect

Tags: react-native, ubuntu, metro-bundler, expo-go

I'm very new to React Native and I'm understanding now Ports and similar things. In the last days I was able to access through Expo Go my app, but starting from today I ran into issues.

I think the problem was, that I was accessing the app using an university wi-fi connection, while the other days I used a mobile data connection. With Wi-Fi I was not able to access the app. The error log said: `java.net.connectException: failed to connect to (...)`

So I started a big journey thorugh ports, ip addresses and firewall, arriving to the ubuntu's `ufw`. Actually I don't know exactly what I've done, but the last try was to disable everything (like it was at the beginning) and retrying to access the app, nothing changed. The error log was: `java.net.SocketTimoutException: failed to connect to (...) from (...)`

I tried also use `tunnel` (like this question says [Unable to connect to Expo React Native Project on WSL2 with Expo Go on phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73311889/unable-to-connect-to-expo-react-native-project-on-wsl2-with-expo-go-on-phone)) but it didn't help. In this case, the app says `New update avalable: downloading...` but never ends.

So, any suggestion to understand a) which is the real problem (a part that I've done something that I didn't understand) and b) how to solve it ?